Get a min of maxes over a moving window in SQ
I'm trying to compute when a charge event will next occur in an event table at any given point in time. Specifically, when a new charge date is entered for a given group, I want to ignore all prior charge dates for that group when looking back across prior rows to get the minimum overall charge date.
Effectively, I want to get the minimum charge date over prior rows, only considering the most recently created entry for each group. Is there a clean way to do this with window functions in bigquery?
Here's a sample of the data I'm discussing and the output I'm expecting:



created_at
group
next_charge_date
goal - next_charge_date across all prior groups




1/1/2024
a
2/21/2024
2/21/2024


1/2/2024
b
2/22/2024
2/21/2024


1/3/2024
a
2/23/2024
2/22/2024


1/4/2024
b
2/22/2024
2/22/2024


1/5/2024
c
2/20/2024
2/20/2024


1/6/2024
a
2/24/2024
2/20/2024


1/7/2024
b
2/23/2024
2/20/2024



I've tried using MIN() & LAST_VALUE() & ROW_NUMBER() functions; however, I don't know an effective way to filter to only the most recently entered prior entry for each group to take my MIN() over. This isn't very hard to do across the entire table, but I don't know how to do it within a moving window.

How did you get 2/22/2024 for your third row? 'a' has never had that 'next_charge_date'

@tinazmu - I want to get the earliest charge over ALL prior groups, not just the group on a given row. However, I want to only consider the most recent entry for each group that occurred on or before a given row. In row 3, 2/22/2024 is the earliest entry across all prior groups ( b and a) looking at the most recent entry on or prior to that row (2/23/2024 for a and 2/22/2024 for b)

' In row 3, 2/22/2024 is the earliest entry across all prior groups ( b and a) l': isn't  2/21/2024 on the first row earlier?

@tinazmu I only want to look over the most recent entry for each group. So as soon as there’s a new entry for group A, we invalidate the prior entry for group a

The second level (getting the min of each of the 'most recent entries of groups) requires filtering, so I believe it requires a subquery; can't be done purely with window functions; but others may know better

Hi @ZackBo. Does my answer solve your issue? BR
